# Get number of root elements in walker class

Tags: menus, walker

I extended `Walker_Nav_Menu` class as below

```
class YPE_custom_navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu{}
```

I want use the `get_number_of_root_elements( $elements )` function that place in to Walker class within my new class `YPE_custom_navwalker`

i want use that function for showing the number of root elements within `start_el` function 
i used this code below but don't work

```
echo $args->walker->get_number_of_root_elements($elements);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after. You can use `$this` to reference the current walker instance.

```
class YPE_custom_navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    public function start_lvl(&$output, $depth=0, $args=array()) {

        $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $args->menu->term_id );
        echo $this->get_number_of_root_elements( $items );

        parent::start_lvl(&$output, $depth,$args);
    }
}
```